# Is there a Slack connector for Botium?

Tags: automated-tests, bots, slack

From the documentation of "Container mode", it seems like Slack is supported: "...while the Chatbot operates as if it is connected to the Facebook Messenger Platform, to the Microsoft Bot Framework, or to the Slack API." However, I've been unable to find any specific reference to a Slack connector.  Our product is a bot accessible through Slack.  We're experimenting with Botium for direct API testing through the Simplerest connector, but would like to test end-to-end through the Slack interface if it exists.  If not, are there plans for developing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one sample available (https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core/tree/master/samples/connectors/docker/slack), and the Botium capabilities are described in the Wiki (https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core/wiki/Operation-Mode-docker). It is not E2E-Testing, it's more a system test - when using Botium like this, your Slack bot is never connected to the Slack servers, everything is intercepted by Botium. If you alread have an API Test with the HTTP/JSON connector in place, then it possibly won't add much to your test strategy.

For E2E-Testing, Botium has a connector providing a framework for running Selenium and Appium tests on websites hosting a chatbot: https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-webdriverio - never tried myself, but I guess it could be used for testing a Slack bot in the Slack ui as well.